Marginal densities and integrating with respect to a law
Here are the definitions/results I've been given:

A random variable $X$ is a map between measurable spaces $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\to (E, \mathcal{E})$.
The law of a random variable $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})\to (E, \mathcal{E})$ is the measure $P_X$ on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ given by $P_X(S) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(S))$ for $S\in \mathcal{E}$. One writes $\mathbb{P}(X\in S)$ to denote $P_X(S)$.
A random variable $X$ in $(\mathbb R^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R^d), \lambda)$ (where $\lambda$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure) has density $p:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb{R}_+$ if $$P_X(B) = \int_B p(x)dx \label{1}\tag{$*$}$$ for all Borel $B$ ($\mathbb{R}_+$ denotes the nonnegative real numbers)
If $\int_\Omega |X| d\mathbb{P} < \infty$ or $X \geq 0$, then we define expectations by $$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega). $$
One can then show $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_E f(x)dP_X(x)$ for $X$ taking values in $E$.

My notes then begin to prove the following result:
Lemma. Let $X=(X_1,\dots, X_d)$ be a random vector with values in $\mathbb R^d$.  Suppose that $X$ has a density $p(x_1,\dots, x_d)$. Then for every $j\in \{1,\dots, d\}$, $X_j$ has a density given by
$$p_j(x) = \int_{\mathbb  R^{d-1}} p(x_1,\dots, x_{j-1}, x, x_{j+1}, \dots, x_d) dx_1\cdots dx_{j-1}dx_{j+1}\cdots dx_d.$$
Proof. Let $π_j$ be the projection $π_j(x_1, \dots, x_d) = x_j$. Then for every Borel function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}_+$,
$$\mathbb E[f(X_j )] = \mathbb E[f (π_j (X))] \stackrel{(**)}{=} \int_{\mathbb R^d} f (x_j )p(x_1, \dots , x_d) dx_1 \dots dx_d = \cdots\label{2}\tag{$\ast\ast$} $$
and the proof in the notes continue.
Question: why does the equality \eqref{2} hold? By the results earlier, $$ \mathbb E[f(\pi_j(X))] = \int_{\mathbb R^{d}} f(\pi_j(x)) dP_X(x).  $$
How does one connect this to integrating with density? The only relation I can see is $P_X(B) = \int_B p(x)dx$, but I don't know how this can be 'substituted' in. Maybe I'm missing some basic measure-theoretic result.

Your assumption about $()$  is correct.  The basic measure-theoretic result you are missing is that when we know how a measure (here $P_X$) evaluates on sets of the $\sigma$-algebra ($B$ in $()$) then we know how to integrate w.r.t. that measure. Esp. when it has a density. This should be part of every textbook.

If the law $P_X$ is associated with a density $p$, it suffices to show that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) dP_X = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)p(x)dx$$
where $dx$ represents the Lebesgue measure. By definition, this is true for Borel indicators. By linearity the result then holds for any simple function and thus for arbitrary measurable $f$ by monotone convergence.
